# webcolors installs, but doesn't import

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a tkinter program, and I am trying to install and import the webcolors module to convert scale values into a hex value. When I run `pip install webcolors` in the cmd, it shows as installed, but when I put `import webcolors` in my program, there is and error saying that webcolors isn't a module. I am using python IDLE and am on windows 10.

My code:

```py
from tkinter import *
import webcolors
root = Tk()
rsv = IntVar()
gsv = IntVar()
bsv = IntVar()
rs = Scale(root, label='red value', variable=rsv, from_=0, to=255)
gs = Scale(root, label='green value', variable=gsv, from_=0, to=255)
bs = Scale(root, label='blue value', variable=bsv, from_=0, to=255)
rs.pack()
gs.pack()
bs.pack()
lbl = Label(root)
lbl.pack()
while True:
    lbl['bg'] = webcolors.rgb_to_hex((rsv.get(), gsv.get(), bsv.get()))
    root.update()
```

Comment: Make sure you have used same Python environment on installing the module and running your script.  If you use IDE, the IDE may create its own Python virtual environment which may not be the one you use in cmd.

Comment: @acw1668 How can I check if my IDE is creating a virtual environment?

Comment: Read the document of the IDE you used.  I normally use a light-weight editor and a command shell, so I cannot tell you how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was installing in a different python version on my computer, I was able to use `cd` and install it on the correct version.